# create data.table with column name from string variable

Tags: r, data.table

i want to create a data.table and I want to use dynamic column names, by the way this is not about adding columns to an existing data.table.

Here is an example

```
outer.name <- "outer.column"
outer.members <- c("I", "II")
outer.members.cnt <- length(outer.members)
dt.outerinner <- data.table(outer = outer.members)
setnames(dt.outerinner, outer.name)
```

Now I want to know, if it's possible to pass the variable "outer.name" directly to `data.table(... = outer.members)` and omit `setnames(...)`?

Any hint is appreciated

Tom

Comment: Can you explain why you are not happy with what you have? It's efficient and very readable code.

Comment: I doubt if it possible, although an interesting question. You could do the whole thing in one line if it helps, something like `setnames(dt.outerinner <- data.table(outer.name = outer.members), outer.name)`

Comment: I love chain!! `library(magrittr); data.table(outer.members) %>% setnames(outer.name) -> dt.outerinner`

Comment: @Roland I'm happy with what I have. I'm just wondering :-)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for your input. My question stems from the fact, that I'm very flexible using .SD and .SDcols when a data.table already exists. So I was just wandering if it's possible to use a variable as a column name (maybe a matter of complete control without the additional setnames function). I'm very happy with the solution, just wanted to make sure that there is no thing missing.

Comment: Your question is interesting (as mentioned) and I agree that it could be a great feature if you could evaluate a column name within `data.table()`. This feature already exists when you already have a `data.table` object, then you can do something like `dt.outerinner[,(outer.name) := outer]`. You could maybe be post a feature request at Github

Comment: @kohske Thanks for mentioning chaining, I'm trying to get used to it :-) Due to the fact that I'm still struggling to get all my tasks done, I'm avoiding to mix it with chaining. Next Step

Comment: @DavidArenburg Due to the fact that I'm not that familiar with git it will take a moment to add this as a feature request :-)

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/labels/feature%20request

Comment: I don't follow. What if the RHS contains more than one column? You'd need to wrap that in a list?? But why? I find using `setnames()` clearer. Piping is nice when done interactively IMHO. It makes things harder to debug, say if you write a package. I don't yet see how to debug intermediate steps with it.. But maybe it's possible, and I'm just not aware of it. Not sure.

Comment: @Arun This question comes from my current project, that I'm working on. I'm trying to build a package that visualizes something. The Interface between the user is a function, he passes a data.table, some character vectors, and some parameters. that the function "knows" how to treat the "incoming" data.table. During the data.preparation the function creates some additional data.tables. This is the point, where I was wondering, if a variable can be directly used as a column name for one of the additional data.tables like .SDcols. I just wanted to know if it's possible. I'm happy with setnames.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be what you want?

```
outer.name <- "outer.column"
outer.members <- c("I", "II")
dtfinal = data.table()
dtfinal[ , (outer.name) := outer.members]
```

First create a placeholder for you `data.table`, then update it by reference using the usual `:=` operator. Use parenthesis to pass in a column name programmatically.